# Creating content programming around a video playlist

Tags: javascript, algorithm, video, time, duration

I'de like to create a "always-on" feel to playing videos by taking said-videos (of different lengths) and stringing them together to create a playlist.

I'm trying to then see if videos fit with 24hr span or is longer. Based on this, when a user comes in, using their current timestamp to jump to that time in the video playlist.

For example -- 
I have 5 videos in an object.

```
{ a: 3.54, b: 8.32, c: 15.23, d: 38.16, e: 68:13}
```

I would then convert these durations to seconds.
24 hours to seconds = 86400

On load to page, check current time in seconds, and see where to sync up to in the video playlist. Where I get stuck is, what if the playlist total duration is > 86400?

What would then be the adjustment to accomodate for the spill over the next 24 hours and continue for each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having stems from the fact that you only check the time of day, which is equivalent to restarting the playlists at midnight each day. This creates discrepancies both with playlists whose length doesn't divide 24 hours equally, and playlists which are longer than 24 hours.

The easiest solution is to treat all the playlists as if they have been looping since a fixed time in the past.

In the code example I've chosen the beginning of the year as the starting point, but you could also use the timestamp when the playlist was last updated; that way, after creating or updating a playlist, it will start playing with the first video, and then loop endlessly.

Run the code snippet (repeatedly) to see this in action.

```js
// FIND ELAPSED TIME SINCE START POINT
var then = new Date("January 1, 2016 00:00:00"); // or use playlist creation timestamp
var now = new Date();
var interval = Math.round((now - then) / 1000);
document.write("interval: " + interval + " seconds<br>");

// CALCULATE LENGTH IN SECONDS OF PLAYLIST (IF UNKNOWN)
var playlist = {a: 3.54, b: 8.32, c: 15.23, d: 38.16, e: 68.13};
var length = 0;
for (var i in playlist) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(playlist[i]);
    var seconds = (minutes * 60) + Math.round((playlist[i] * 100) % 100);
    length += seconds;
}
document.write("length: " + length + " seconds<br>");

// CALCULATE CURRENT POSITION IN PLAYLIST
var position = interval % length;
document.write("position in playlist: " + position + " seconds<br>");

// CALCULATE CURRENT POSITION IN VIDEO
for (var i in playlist) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(playlist[i]);
    var seconds = (minutes * 60) + Math.round((playlist[i] * 100) % 100);
    if (position < seconds) {
        document.write("video: " + i + "<br>position in video: " + position + " seconds");
        break;
    }
    else position -= seconds;
}
```

Comment: this is absolutely great! love the implementation here. using your method of basing off a specific time (love the idea of doing it based on most recent, as it starts with newest)

my question -- 
if i were to loop through the videos to cut it to fit into 24 hours (remainder not being shown), then using your logic, it seems like it could work great. the remaining "empty air" time would be an offline visual cue.

does this make sense?

Comment: @Yasir You could measure the interval since the playlist's update timestamp, and then use `interval % 86400` to see where you are in the playlist. This would be like re-starting the playlist every day at the time it was last updated. If the position is beyond the end of the playlist, you could then show some kind of "off air" message.

Comment: @Yasir Or do you mean you want long playlists to stop playing at midnight?

Comment: I like the idea of "off air" so that way it doesn't cut content that goes past midnight.

Seems like there's two options --
1. let it loop at anytime the total video playlist is finished
2. fit content within 24 hours, and start the video playlist back up each midnight of following day

Your solution solves for 1 correct? I actually like your method better, since its always continuous and no off-air message is shown.

Comment: @Yasir Yes, continuous looping (option 1) seemed like the most logical solution to me.

Comment: agree, you did the solution one better! kudos!